# Reading an array of UDT values from an ExtensionObject using the Python opcua library

Tags: python, plc, siemens

I have a Siemens 1500 PLC with a datablock that contains and array of UDT object, that in themselves contain different data in the form of regular datatypes.

[Datablock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h0E8.png)

Using the opcua Python library I am able to connect to the PLC and get individual values from the array using the specific values node ID's, however, I would like to download the entire datablock in one connection, then access and parse the datacblock client side using Python code. When I download the entire datablock it is an ExtensionObject, that I know contains all the data, but it is in the form of a bytearray.

How do I access all the data in an ExtensionObject?

Thank you

I have tried loading client.load_type_definitions() but that did not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.